# INSERT..RETURNING is not working in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, jooq

I have a MariaDB database and I'm trying to insert a row in my table `users`. It has a generated `id` and I want to get it after insert. I have seen [this](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-returning/) but it's not working for me:

```
public Integer addNewUser(String name) {
    Record record = context.insertInto(table("users"), field("name"))
        .values(name)
        .returning(field("id"))
        .fetchOne();
    return record.into(Integer.class);
}
```

New row is inserted but `record` is always `null`. I'm not using JOOQ code generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation in jOOQ 3.9: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2943

You currently cannot use the `RETURNING` clause in jOOQ when using [plain SQL tables and fields](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) (as opposed to generated ones), because jOOQ needs to know the identity column name to bind to JDBC (in most databases), and that meta data is not available from your `table("users")` object.

Unfortunately, passing the `ID` column to the `RETURNING` clause isn't sufficient, because there's no guarantee that this is the identity column. You might also pass several columns to the `RETURNING` clause, in case of which jOOQ wouldn't know which one would be the identity column.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, I will need to query the max value and add 1, right? Is there another way in order to take advantage of the auto-increment?

Comment: @bigdestroyer: I wouldn't query the max value, as that might lead to race conditions. I'd search for the user by name again, as it's probably unique. Or, you use the jOOQ code generator, in case of which this query will return the id correctly

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: But the OP's example was not plain SQL, how is this answer relevant? At least, for me plain SQL would mean not going through the DSL

Comment: @Dici: `table("users")` is a plain SQL template. From the jOOQ side, it doesn't matter if only query elements or the entire query are plain SQL templates, the underlying problem is that no meta data is available to know which column is the identity. Well, what I said in the answer, if you want...

Comment: Mm ok thanks, I read more about the code generation so I see what you meant, but perhaps "plain SQL" is a little confusing to use here.

Comment: @Dici Is it really? I've added "plain SQL tables and fields". I mean, how else would you want to describe those? They're templates, even if there are no placeholders or logic in them, only identifiers...

Comment: That's a DSL, not plain SQL. I would find this terminology more accurate. That said you were close to jOOQ so if you tell me that's the terminology you use, then so be it, just saying for me it was not immediately obvious what you meant there. Anyway!

Comment: work* not were (can't edit my comment anymore)

Comment: @Dici: In the context of this question, it's irrelevant if people write `table("some_name")` or `table("(select a, b from t)")`. It's the same method. Just because your plain SQL is but a SQL identifier doesn't matter. If your Java program is "just" `int a = 1` doesn't make it any less of a Java program. In fact, this is the whole point. It's using the plain SQL APIs, which prevents `RETURNING` from working here, irrespective of the intention of using this API, or the perception of what many other things the API might represent.

Comment: Oh boy... yeah not worth continuing.