# JOOQ's insert...returning with PostgreSQL 10 and JOOQ 3.10?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq, postgresql-10

It seems that JOOQ's *insert... returning* does not work for generated code.

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264116/insert-returning-is-not-working-in-jooq) issue which deals with plain SQL, however i am not using plain SQL.

This is the questionable line:

```java
public Integer add(MemberRecord member) {
// always returns 1
    return dslContext.insertInto(MEMBER).set(member).returning(MEMBER.ID).execute(); 
}
```

Member table has a serial id as a primary key.
Generated query is correct and if i execute it manually it will return id generated by sequence.

```sql
 -- ID is not specified in values list
 insert into "member" ("name", ...) returning "member"."id"
```

Database is PostgreSQL 10, JOOQ version is 3.10.8.

Am i doing something wrong with JOOQ or this is an issue, perhaps fixed already in some of the newer versions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute()` will return the number of rows inserted/updated/deleted by the query. You'll want to call one of the `fetch()` variants like `fetchOne()`.

Javadoc:

- https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#execute--
- https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertResultStep.html#fetchOne--

Comment: oooh, self note, starting read JOOQs javadoc instead of guessing. It seems a bit unintuitve to me that i can specify field in returning and then again need to specify the same field with fetchOne().getId()

Comment: @John: That is a historic API design issue, that is partially fixed in jOOQ 3.11 through https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6715. You could use [`returningResult`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertReturningStep.html#returningResult-org.jooq.SelectField-) and then you would get a `Record1<Integer>` or similar type when calling `fetchOne()`. Unfortunately, with Java generics, it's not possible for the [`InsertResultStep`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertResultStep.html) type's method to *know* they're returning only one column.